# Make one-to-one relation between two tables that have one-to-many relation in SQL

Tags: sql-server, join, right-to-left, right-join

I have these queries :

```
SELECT        
    dbo.Lines.Unit, dbo.Lines.LineNumber, dbo.Lines.DocumentNumber, 
    dbo.BaseMaterials.Name AS MaterialName, 
    dbo.MaterialDescriptions.Name AS MaterialDescription, 
    dbo.MaterialDescriptions.Description, 
    dbo.MaterialScopes.ScopeName, dbo.MaterialScopeObjectNames.ObjectName, 
    dbo.MaterialDescriptions.Size1, dbo.MaterialDescriptions.Size2, 
    dbo.MaterialDescriptions.ItemCode, dbo.Materials.Quantity, 
    dbo.Materials.Discipline, dbo.Materials.Id, dbo.Lines.Id AS LineId
FROM
    dbo.Materials 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Lines ON dbo.Materials.LineId = dbo.Lines.Id 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.BaseMaterials ON dbo.Lines.BaseMaterialId = dbo.BaseMaterials.Id 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.MaterialDescriptions ON dbo.Materials.MaterialDescriptionId = dbo.MaterialDescriptions.Id 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.MaterialScopes ON dbo.MaterialDescriptions.MaterialScopeId = dbo.MaterialScopes.Id 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.MaterialScopeObjectNames ON dbo.MaterialDescriptions.MaterialScopeObjectId = dbo.MaterialScopeObjectNames.Id
```

It returns 16000 records. I have another tables with `joints` name that has a relation with `material` table on `lineId` every `material`  can have `multi joints` so my query when I add `joints` table is like this :

```
SELECT        
    dbo.Lines.Unit, dbo.Lines.LineNumber, dbo.Lines.DocumentNumber, 
    dbo.BaseMaterials.Name AS MaterialName, 
    dbo.MaterialDescriptions.Name AS MaterialDescription, 
    dbo.MaterialDescriptions.Description, dbo.MaterialScopes.ScopeName, 
    dbo.MaterialScopeObjectNames.ObjectName, dbo.MaterialDescriptions.Size1, 
    dbo.MaterialDescriptions.Size2, dbo.MaterialDescriptions.ItemCode, 
    dbo.Materials.Quantity, dbo.Materials.Discipline, dbo.Materials.Id, 
    dbo.Lines.Id AS LineId, dbo.Joints.TestPackageId
FROM
    dbo.Materials 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Lines ON dbo.Materials.LineId = dbo.Lines.Id 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.BaseMaterials ON dbo.Lines.BaseMaterialId = dbo.BaseMaterials.Id 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.MaterialDescriptions ON dbo.Materials.MaterialDescriptionId = dbo.MaterialDescriptions.Id 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.MaterialScopes ON dbo.MaterialDescriptions.MaterialScopeId = dbo.MaterialScopes.Id 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.MaterialScopeObjectNames ON dbo.MaterialDescriptions.MaterialScopeObjectId = dbo.MaterialScopeObjectNames.Id 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Joints ON dbo.Materials.LineId = dbo.Joints.LineId
```

As you can see in the last line i make a join between `joints` and `materials` to access the `testpackageid` column in `joints` table .but my result returns 220000records .How can i change the join type i mean `left` or `right` to just returns `16000` records with its `testpackageId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't using `JOIN`.  However, you can using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
FROM . . .
     dbo.MaterialScopeObjectNames
     ON dbo.MaterialDescriptions.MaterialScopeObjectId = dbo.MaterialScopeObjectNames.Id CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 j.*
      FROM dbo.Joints j
      WHERE dbo.Materials.LineId = j.LineId
     ) J
```

Normally, you would include an `ORDER BY` when using `TOP` so you have some control over the row being returned.

Also note that the use of table aliases makes the query easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it very easily with just a subquery. Leave your query as it is, and add a subquery to get that information from Joints.

```
SELECT        dbo.Lines.Unit, dbo.Lines.LineNumber, dbo.Lines.DocumentNumber, dbo.BaseMaterials.Name AS MaterialName, dbo.MaterialDescriptions.Name AS MaterialDescription, dbo.MaterialDescriptions.Description, 
                         dbo.MaterialScopes.ScopeName, dbo.MaterialScopeObjectNames.ObjectName, dbo.MaterialDescriptions.Size1, dbo.MaterialDescriptions.Size2, dbo.MaterialDescriptions.ItemCode, dbo.Materials.Quantity, 
                         dbo.Materials.Discipline, dbo.Materials.Id, dbo.Lines.Id AS LineId,
                         (select top 1 dbo.Joints.TestPackageId from dbo.Joints where dbo.Joints.LineId = dbo.Materials.LineId)
FROM            dbo.Materials INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Lines ON dbo.Materials.LineId = dbo.Lines.Id INNER JOIN
                         dbo.BaseMaterials ON dbo.Lines.BaseMaterialId = dbo.BaseMaterials.Id INNER JOIN
                         dbo.MaterialDescriptions ON dbo.Materials.MaterialDescriptionId = dbo.MaterialDescriptions.Id INNER JOIN
                         dbo.MaterialScopes ON dbo.MaterialDescriptions.MaterialScopeId = dbo.MaterialScopes.Id INNER JOIN
                         dbo.MaterialScopeObjectNames ON dbo.MaterialDescriptions.MaterialScopeObjectId = dbo.MaterialScopeObjectNames.Id
```

Comment: Thank you .Yes i know but i thought maybe there is a better solution .